# mod_rewrite Rules for Not Showing 'index/' on Home Page - PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen lots on the subject but I can't seem to get this thing working like I want...

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

And everything seems to work fine.  When I go to, for example

```
localhost/website
```

the contents from

```
localhost/website/index.php
```

are displayed.  This is expected.  My links are in variables in PHP, like so:

```
$home = 'index/'
$contact = 'contact/'
```

etc, etc...

So then I go to other links, click around a bit, and then click on the Home link and the URL is now this:

```
localhost/website/index/
```

which is what my `href` points to, so it's expected...  But I really want it to be:

```
localhost/website
```

So how do I use the variable `$home = '';` instead of `$home = index/';` and get what I want above?  I feel like Im missing something that should go in the `.htaccess` file.

I guess I should also mention that the way my navigation works is I have a PHP loop that checks for current page in order to keep its graphic highlighted as opposed to not.

This loop checks the page variables, eg `$home`, `$contact`, and if they are equal to the key value in an array full of page variables, then it use the highlighted set for links:  this has the effect of the page you're on having light colored buttons.

The problem here is that for the index page, I'm using `'index/'` but I want to use `''` but this seems to not work.  It works when the conditional checks for `'index/'` but not when it checks for an empty string (`''`).

**EDIT**

Here are some additional code snippets that may help my case:

```
// Navigation links
$home           =   '';
$contact_us     =   'contact/';

// Button array
$page_nav_lt = array(
$home           =>  $home_but_lt,
$contact_us     =>  $contact_but_lt
);

// Loop conditional (it's _alt below because it's a function in a class)
if ($current_page == $key) {
    $menu_output .= $image_dir . $ds . $page_nav_alt[$key];
    $menu_output .= '" id="alt" class="data-id-yes';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$home = '';`, and add this to your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

I included index.html as an example, but you can have as many default filenames as you would like, and it will check for them in order.

Edit:  you can test for home as '', but `<a href="">` will just point at the current page.  Normally to link to a home page, you would link to '/', which points at the root directory of your server.  Since your site is being tested in a subdirectory, you want it to be '/site/'.  You can make your links work in different environments by setting a $root variable to '/site', then change it to '' when you move your site to the root.  Then your links will look like '/site/' and '/site/contact'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried it and it directs correctly but the link doesn't remain highlighted, which is what I need.  Somehow I need the loop in the navigation to test for it being  the index page so it will be highlighted.  I'm going to add an edit to clarify.

Comment: In your loop, what does it tell you the page url is when you are on the home page?

Comment: When I echo the `$current_page` variable it shows nothing, probably because it's an empty string.  Is that what you are asking?  My apologies for my dense-ness.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You might also post your code that compares the current page to your link variables.  It sounds likely that the problem is there.

Comment: I added some extra snippets that hopefully will help show this.

Comment: hmm... it's not obvious without seeing what happens in between, but I would try doing var_dump on those variables right before you test them.  (Wrap it in pre tags first, or view the source).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17277/discussion-between-brian-mortenson-and-nicorellius)